# query returns null and expecting a 1

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, mysqli

This is a name check and is expecting a result of 1 when checking username with users in my database.

Unfortunately, I am getting a null response (so echo error 5).  Please if anyone sees a problem with php I be very grateful

code

```
$username = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$namecheckquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ' " . $username . " ' ";

$namecheck = mysqli_query($con, $namecheckquery) or die("2: name check query failed"); // error code #2 = name check query failed
if(mysqli_num_rows ($nameCheck) !=1)
{
    echo "5: Either no user with name, more than one."; //error code number 5 number names does not match one
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Your query is prone to SQL injection attacks. You should learn about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: i am aware but started learning this, want to get it working then make it better

Comment: Are you sure you get a null response? Have you dumped the $namecheck variable?
The if condition  just checks if resource number of rows is not 1. But this means more things... not that it is null.

Comment: WWW www = new WWW("http://kevincranfieldwebdesigner.com/mysqlconnect/login.php", form);
        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.error);

Comment: i thought null as my c# script in unity calls null in debug.log(www.error).

Comment: User login failed. Error#object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(4)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
6: Incorrect password
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoginPlayer>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/login.cs:41)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Answer (score 0):

If you print the query, you'll notice that there are spaces around $username and you can't get a result unless you've inserted the username with those spaces.

Wrong query string when you enter John as username:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ' John '
//                             Wrong spaces  ^    ^
```

Remove the spaces between double and single quotes:

```
$namecheckquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
```

Even better, remove spaces and avoid concatenation:

```
$namecheckquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
```

PHP will replace variables with their corresponding values when a string is enclosed between double quotes.

Finally, the query is not returning null, function mysqli_num_rows($nameCheck) is returning 0 because there were no matches found.

Comment: Thank you but still getting error 5 :            User login failed. Error# object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(4)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
5: Either no user with name, more than one.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoginPlayer>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/login.cs:41)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Comment: need to find out why im not getting matches

Comment: Yes, indeed. Print the query, copy it and execute it in PhpMyAdmin and see what's happening there.

Comment: I am thinking if i was not getting a match would the code end at error 2?

Comment: No, you only can get error code 2 if there is an error in the SQL query so it can't be executed.

Comment: I dumped $namecheckquery and $namecheck first is fine namecheck looks like it is wrong